# Cannot get different remote actors to run across different machines

Tags: akka, akka-remote-actor

The problem i have is that i can create the system on another slave machine. But i cant figure out how to distribute parts onto different machines. IE master, slave1 and slave2 all end up on same machine rather than ip 101,102 and 103 respectively.

I am using a master server to essentially manage a workflow of messages through several servers.
So the master starts up creates the master server actor which then does the following:

- Master:
  1. sends a start message to slave 1
  2. takes a success message from slave 1 and passes a message to slave 2
  3. takes a success message from slave 2 then shuts down the system
- Slave1: takes a message from server and replies to master with success
- Slave2: takes a message from server and replies to master with success

Later i want to scale each of these horizontally - however hit a problem before that.
All the remote stuff will only run on 1 machine.

I am using remote so that part of the config looks like this:

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
    deployment {
      "/masterCreatorActor/*" {
        remote = "akka.tcp://RemoteActorSystem@192.168.56.101:2552"
      }
      "/slave1Actor/*" {
        remote = "akka.tcp://RemoteActorSystem@192.168.56.102:2552"
      }
      "/slave2Actor/*" {
        remote = "akka.tcp://RemoteActorSystem@192.168.56.103:2552"
      }
    }
  }
```

The code to create the actorSystem and master actor

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load("remotecreation")
val system = ActorSystem("PromoAnalysisSystem", config)
def act = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MasterCreatorActor],OnFinished _),
                   name = "masterCreatorActor" )
```

then inside the master actor I use slave1 by doing this when it receives a message:

```
val slave1 = context.actorOf(Props[Slave1Actor],name = "slave1Actor")
slave1 ! slave1StartMessage
```

So I can host the system all on 1 machine. I can also start it on 1 machine and have it all run on another remote machine. But i cannot get each of the actors in the config to run on different machines.

I am being stupid but cant see in what way! ;)

Comment: Have you tried /*/slave1Actor?

Comment: assuming you mean as name parameter: didnt work.  akka.actor.InvalidActorNameException: illegal actor name [/*/heartbeatActor], must conform to (?:[-\w:@&=+,.!~*'_;]|%\p{XDigit}{2})(?:[-\w:@&=+,.!~*'$_;]|%\p{XDigit}{2})* ... but that gave me an idea

Comment: Sorry.. I meant in the config.

Comment: /*/slave1Actor/*  is what he meant (legend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
    deployment {
      "/masterCreatorActor/*" {
        remote = "akka.tcp://RemoteActorSystem@192.168.56.101:2552"
      }
      "/*/slave1Actor/*" {
        remote = "akka.tcp://RemoteActorSystem@192.168.56.102:2552"
      }
      "/*/slave2Actor/*" {
        remote = "akka.tcp://RemoteActorSystem@192.168.56.103:2552"
      }
    }
  }
```